# Visual Studio studio custom template: Some usings are automatically parameters (they automatically change when imported)

Tags: templates, parameters

The MSDN on templates and template parameters is completely f****ng useless.. I can't even follow the instructions because it implies I have access to files that don't exist yet (like .vstemplate), and god forbid it provides some directories for this stuff.

Anyway I tried to make do and I thought I figured it out.. But apparently not:

I made a class file to export to a template that looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using NovaTech.Framework;
using NovaTech.Utilities;

namespace $rootnamespace$
{
    public class $safeitemname$ : BaseComponent
    {
        public $safeitemname$() : base()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

But when i export it to a template and reimport it, it looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using **NovaTech.NED.AssetComponents**.Framework;
using **NovaTech.NED.AssetComponents**.Utilities;

namespace NovaTech.NED.AssetComponents
{
    public class NEDComponent1 : BaseComponent
    {
        public NEDComponent1() : base()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

(EDIT: Those parts surrounded in ** ** were supposed to be bolded..)

EDIT: (fixed one of the problems I had, only 1 left):
Notice the two usings there changing despite them not being marked as parameters in the template. The two usings are not supposed to be parameters, yet for some reason it treats them like they are. How can I stop this from happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to find a solution. I figured out that it replaces my usings with parameters (why, I still don't know) during EXPORTING, not importing. So I just exported the template, replaced the .cs file with a CORRECT one, and when I reimported it everything was as it should be.